# Adding several nodes as TabPane content

Tags: user-interface, tabs, javafx-2, javafx

I am currently trying to add some content to a tabPane with the method:

```
tab.setContent(label, combobox);
```

Sadly this method only allows me to add 1 component to my tab so how do I work around this limitation? Do I need to create a new class and add that stage as a component or is there another way?

Update:

I'm sorry my original question was not clear enough here is a brief explanation:

So I've created my GUI in JavaFx Scene builder and i have created a tabPane where i have three different tabs. All of which needs to contain different things now depending on which button you click on in my GUI i want to change the content of the tabs therefore i need to write the code my self my.

My problem is that i want to add components to my tab manually yet i am unable to because the tab.setContent method allows me to only add 1 component! also i am unable to set the component where i want it to be it kinda stays in the top left corner!

Comment: What exactly is your problem?

Comment: Oh, I think I get it. You can add as many things (comboboxes, whatever) as youd like to a node and then add the node to the tab.

Comment: The problem is that i cannot add more than 1 component to my tab

Comment: @TheUnfunCat how do i make a node?

Comment: You are using javafx 2 right?

Comment: yep im actually using JavaFx scene builder to create the most of my Gui

Comment: Create eg a http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/layout/VBox.html then add the combobox and all the other stuff youd like to that VBox. Do'nt have time to write more now, will get back to this unless someone else answers.

Comment: @TheUnfunCat sadly adding components to a box does not forfill the purpose i have for these tabs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use any layout manager as content:

```
FlowPane pane = new FlowPane();
pane.getChildren().addAll(new Label("Hello"), new Label(", world"));
tab.setContent(pane);
```